# EMF and faraday law

Tags: electromagnetism

When the magnetic flux is 8 and then changes to 4 and then returns to 8, this results in emf, although if we apply the law, the result is emf = 0

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The mean emf is induced in a coil is zero, and if the flux changes happened very quickly your voltmeter might possibly show just this – zero. But if the changes happened slowly or your meter responded rapidly you might notice the induced voltage rising to a maximum, dropping to zero and rising to a maximum in the other direction before dropping back again.